# how do i fix android studio sdk error sdk 30.0.2 error sdk

Tags: android

android studio to error helppp!
Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: D:\sdk

Answer (score 1):

- In the SDK Manager go to SDK Tools.
- There you should check **Show Package Details**.
- At the appeared list choose those ones that are shown in your error.